# How to extract String from a Column datatype in Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a function which accepts a String parameter and does a "match" on it to determine return values, like this -

**Edit(Complete function):**

```
 def getSubscriptionDaysFunc(account_status:Column, created_at: org.apache.spark.sql.Column, updated_at: org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column = {
account_status match {
    case "expired" =>datediff(updated_at,created_at)
    case "cancelled" =>datediff(updated_at,created_at)
    case "active" =>datediff(updated_at, current_date())
    case default => null 
} }
```

This function is called in this way -

```
df.withColumn("subscription_days", getSubscriptionDaysFunc($"account_status",$"created_at",$"updated_at"))
```

Here $"account_status" returns a "Column" value. How do I get the String value from the "Column" object?

Edit: I also tried writing a UDF in the following way -

```
val getSubscriptionDaysFunc = udf((account_status:String, created_at: org.apache.spark.sql.Column, updated_at: org.apache.spark.sql.Column):Column =>  {
account_status match {
case "expired" =>datediff(updated_at,created_at)
case "cancelled" =>datediff(updated_at,created_at)
case "active" => datediff(updated_at, current_date())
case default => null
} })
```

This gives the error -

> "error: illegal start of declaration   account_status match {" .

Comment: what you want to implement is an UDF

Comment: Can you not match the Column like this -> https://gist.github.com/rahulj51/7dae268d4bb8bc1ac5ca75af16877f61

Comment: @Rahul In this case, "Column" is an in-built datatype (org.apache.spark.sql.Column) and not my custom class. Is it still possible to define a case class?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is to implement an UDF:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val getSubscriptionDaysFunc = udf((account_status:String) =>  {
  account_status match {
    case "expired" =>//some logic
    case "cancelled" =>//some logic
    case "active" =>//some logic
    case default => null
  } 
})

df.withColumn("subscription_days", getSubscriptionDaysFunc($"account_status"))
```

Comment: I tried with a udf(see edit), I get this error - "error: illegal start of declaration." at "account_status match {"

Comment: @user1571307 your syntax is incorrect, you don't use a return type annotation for a function.  UDF also should receive and return values, not column

Comment: @puhlen : Ok. datediff returns a "Column", so how do I extract value from it(that's my question here too)? As for return value, when I don't specify Column as return value I get an error "UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Column is not supported"

Comment: @puhlen Thanks to your comment, I removed the return type, and changed all parameters to String type, and I'm now able to get the udf working with hard-coded String return values. Now how do I return correct values using datediff?

Comment: Also datediff accepts only Column datatypes in parameters. If I've got it right, I guess we cant pass anything other than String values to a udf, so maybe a udf is not the way to go?

Comment: @user1571307 UDFs are not restricted to Strings, you can pass all primitives and also array of primitives. But you don't operate with columns inside an UDF. I strongly think you are not understanding the basics of Spark DataFrames

Comment: @RaphaelRoth can you please take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47503696/problems-with-adding-a-new-column-to-a-dataframe-spark-scala
I am having problems similar to this question.