# Problems with adding a new column to a dataframe - spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am new to spark/scala. I am trying to read some data from a hive table to a spark dataframe and then add a column based on some condition. Here is my code:

```
val DF = hiveContext.sql("select * from (select * from test_table where partition_date='2017-11-22') a JOIN (select max(id) as bid from test_table where partition_date='2017-11-22' group by at_id) b ON a.id=b.bid")

def dateDiff(partition_date: org.apache.spark.sql.Column, item_due_date: org.apache.spark.sql.Column): Long ={
      ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(LocalDate.parse(partition_date.toString()), LocalDate.parse(item_due_date.toString))
    }

val finalDF = DF.withColumn("status", 
                   when(col("past_due").equalTo(1) && !(col("item_due_date").equalTo(null) || col("item_due_date").equalTo("NULL") || col("item_due_date").equalTo("null")) && (dateDiff(col("partition_date"),col("item_due_date")) < 0) && !(col("item_decision").equalTo(null) || col("item_decision").equalTo("NULL") || col("item_decision").equalTo("null")), "approved")
                  .when(col("past_due").equalTo(1) && !(col("item_due_date").equalTo(null) || col("item_due_date").equalTo("NULL") || col("item_due_date").equalTo("null")) && (dateDiff(col("partition_date"),col("item_due_date")) < 0) && (col("item_decision").equalTo(null) || col("item_decision").equalTo("NULL") || col("item_decision").equalTo("null")), "pending")
                  .when(col("past_due").equalTo(1) && !(col("item_due_date").equalTo(null) || col("item_due_date").equalTo("NULL") || col("item_due_date").equalTo("null")) && (dateDiff(col("partition_date"),col("item_due_date")) >= 0), "expired")
                  .otherwise("null"))
```

`dateDiff` is a function that calculates the difference between `partition_date` and `item_due_date`, which are columns in `DF`. I am trying to add a new column to `DF` by using `when` and `otherwise` which uses the `dateDiff` to get the difference between dates.

Now, when I run the above code, I get the following error:  `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'partition_date' could not be parsed at index 0`

I believe the value of the column `partition_date` is not being converted to a String to be parsed as a date. Is this what's happening? If yes, how do I cast the column value to a String ?

Below is the schema of the columns I am using from the `DF` :

```
 |-- item_due_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- past_due: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- item_decision: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partition_date: string (nullable = true)
```

A data sample of the columns I am using from the `DF` :

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
|past_due|item_due_date|item_decision|partition_date|
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
|       1|   0001-01-14|         null|    2017-11-22|
|       1|   0001-01-14|     Mitigate|    2017-11-22|
|       1|   0001-01-14|     Mitigate|    2017-11-22|
|       1|   0001-01-14|     Mitigate|    2017-11-22|
|       0|   2018-03-18|         null|    2017-11-22|
|       1|   2016-11-30|         null|    2017-11-22|
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
```

I also tried using a custom UDF:

```
  def status(past_due: Int, item_decision: String, maxPartitionDate: String, item_due_date: String): String = {
      if (past_due == 1 && item_due_date != "NULL") {
        if (ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(LocalDate.parse(maxPartitionDate.trim), LocalDate.parse(item_due_date.trim)) < 0) {
          if (item_decision != "NULL") "pending"
          else "approved"
        } else "expired"
      } else "NULL"
    }

val statusUDF = sqlContext.udf.register("statusUDF", status _)

val DF2 = DF.withColumn("status", statusUDF(DF("past_due"),DF("item_decision"),DF("partition_date"),DF("item_due_date")))
DF2.show()
```

And it throws the following error at the `DF2.show` statement, everytime:

```
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 50

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1433)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1421)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1420)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1420)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1644)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1603)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1592)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1844)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1857)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1870)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Limit.executeCollect(basicOperators.scala:165)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectPublic(SparkPlan.scala:174)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2086)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1(DataFrame.scala:1498)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect(DataFrame.scala:1505)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1375)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1374)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withCallback(DataFrame.scala:2099)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1374)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.take(DataFrame.scala:1456)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.showString(DataFrame.scala:170)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:350)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:311)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:319)
        at driver$.main(driver.scala:109)
        at driver.main(driver.scala)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: your function is column based. so you can utilize [spark functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) if any functions satisfies your needs. Otherwise if you want to manipulate in primitive datatypes you would have to go with udf functions.

Comment: I tried using a UDF instead of `when` and `otherwise`, but I was facing errors while displaying/saving the dataframe. So I switched to this approach. Is there a way I can solve the error in this approach?

Comment: You will have to update your question with sample dataframe and schema of the dataframe. that will help you get answers quickly

Comment: @Hemanth The function you wrote is not `udf`, you should read more careful about how to write apropriate `udf`.

Comment: I know it's not a `UDF`. It's a normal scala function to get the difference in dates. @cue Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: just show us two rows of DF.show and DF.printSchema

Comment: Updated the question with the required details. @RameshMaharjan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `datediff` inbuilt function to check for the days difference between two columns. you don't need to write your function or `udf` function. And when function is also modified than yours

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val finalDF = DF.withColumn("status",
  when(col("past_due").equalTo(1) && col("item_due_date").isNotNull && !(lower(col("item_due_date")).equalTo("null")) && (datediff(col("partition_date"),col("item_due_date")) < 0) && col("item_decision").isNotNull && !(lower(col("item_decision")).equalTo("null")), "approved")
    .otherwise(when(col("past_due").equalTo(1) && col("item_due_date").isNotNull && !(lower(col("item_due_date")).equalTo("null")) && (datediff(col("partition_date"),col("item_due_date")) < 0) && (col("item_decision").isNull || lower(col("item_decision")).equalTo("null")), "pending")
      .otherwise(when(col("past_due").equalTo(1) && col("item_due_date").isNotNull && !(lower(col("item_due_date")).equalTo("null")) && (datediff(col("partition_date"),col("item_due_date")) >= 0), "expired")
    .otherwise("null"))))
```

This logic will convert the `dataframe`

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
|past_due|item_due_date|item_decision|partition_date|
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
|1       |2017-12-14   |null         |2017-11-22    |
|1       |2017-12-14   |Mitigate     |2017-11-22    |
|1       |0001-01-14   |Mitigate     |2017-11-22    |
|1       |0001-01-14   |Mitigate     |2017-11-22    |
|0       |2018-03-18   |null         |2017-11-22    |
|1       |2016-11-30   |null         |2017-11-22    |
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
```

with addition of `status` column as

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------+
|past_due|item_due_date|item_decision|partition_date|status  |
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------+
|1       |2017-12-14   |null         |2017-11-22    |pending |
|1       |2017-12-14   |Mitigate     |2017-11-22    |approved|
|1       |0001-01-14   |Mitigate     |2017-11-22    |expired |
|1       |0001-01-14   |Mitigate     |2017-11-22    |expired |
|0       |2018-03-18   |null         |2017-11-22    |null    |
|1       |2016-11-30   |null         |2017-11-22    |expired |
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: You're a Savior! Thanks a ton! :)

Comment: The program runs without any problems, but I only see `expired` and `null` values in the `status` column. Is there a problem with the logic?

Comment: your dates should be like that. please check with the dates. :)

Comment: That seems to be the case. Also, my ‘when’ condition should also work fine, right ? Would like to know if there is any difference.

Comment: Nope your  when logic has some defects too. I mean the way you wrote it as everything is generating null in the status column . You can try it and see it yourself. debug and improve. I guess you can do that. :)

Comment: I did test out both the ways of writing the `when` conditions and found no difference. Both the ways gave me the same number of `expired` and `null` values in the Final dataframe. I also tested out my `when` function with other dataset for a different scenario and it produced expected results.

Comment: great then. :) may be I did something wrong in my code. I just optimized your codes by using inbuilt functions. Thats all.